# What does -qq argument for apt-get mean?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I just received a **Vagrantfile** and post install bash script. The vagrantfile downloads standard **Ubuntu** from Ubuntu Cloud but I found something in the bash script.

Few lines of script reads as:

```
apt-get update -qq > /dev/null
apt-get -qq -y install apache2 > /dev/null
```

I tried to search around the internet what `-qq` in shell script stands for, didn't get any mention of it, so, am asking here if anyone knows what it stands for.

AFAIK `> /dev/null` means the ongoing process is not printed in the screen, for that it doesn't require the `-qq` flag. So, I am really curious to know.

Comment: This relates to http://askubuntu.com/questions/258219/how-do-i-make-apt-get-install-less-noisy

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The `-qq` is a flag to `apt-get` to make it less noisy.

```
-qq No output except for errors
```

You are correct about the `>/dev/null`. By redirecting all the STDOUT, the `-qq` becomes redundant.

Comment: The -qq would only be redundant if a "-y" was included instead.

Answer (score 18):

The `-qq` makes it very quiet instead of only quiet. But from my man page, it also implies `-y` (`--assume-yes`, answers "yes" to the questions), and the man warns the use of `-qq`:

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

> Note that quiet level 2 implies -y, you should never use -qq without a
>   no-action modifier such as -d, --print-uris or -s as APT may decided
>   to do something you did not expect.

You could ask developer of this script to check it.

Answer (score 13):

In this case `-qq` is an option to apt-get and not bash.  If you do man apt-get you will get the documentation for apt-get.

It means "really quiet"

```
-q, --quiet
    Quiet. Produces output suitable for logging, omitting progress indicators. More q's will produce more quiet up to a maximum of two. You can also use -q=# to set the quiet level, overriding the configuration file. Note that quiet level 2 implies -y, you should never use -qq without a no-action modifier such as -d, --print-uris or -s as APT may decided to do something you did not expect.
```

So, to summarize a call to `apt-get` will be more verbose than `apt-get -q` which is more verbose than `apt-get -qq`.

Generally the first place to look for any help on a command is that command's "man" page.  `man` is a standard Linux command that will display help for the given command.  So in your case, `man apt-get` would give you help for the apt-get command.